# Evaluating the Limit of 2 Variables

Tags: calculus, limits

If I have a function $f(x,y)$ and I need to evaluate following limit;$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} f(x,y)$

Could I calculate the limit of $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,x) \rightarrow (0,0)} f(x,x)$ and that be equal to$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} f(x,y)$? I thought since they're both approaching the same value, then they're the same, right? Or are they not equal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace $y$ by $x$, you're actually taking the limit towards $(0,0)$ by approaching along the line $y=x$. This is usually referred to as a *path*. You could also substitute $y=0$ and let $x \to 0$, this would be approaching along the $x$-axis (or vice versa, via the $y$-axis).

But there are more exotic paths as well, such as the parabola $y=x^2$ mentioned in Christopher Carl Heckman's answer. In fact, that are an *infinite number of paths* to approach from! Just choosing one, unfortunately isn't enough. Even trying many isn't, unless the limit doesn't exist.

**If** a limit of a function in two variables **exists**, then the value of the one dimensional limits you get when approaching it along a certain path, should be **independent of the path**. This means that if you can find two paths that give you a different limit, the limit **does not exist**. This is sometimes referred to as the *path test*.

When you have tried a few paths and you think the limit does in fact exist, then you'll need to use other methods to actually show this. That could be the formal ($\varepsilon-\delta$) definition, or algebraic manipulations etc.

---

> Limit does not exist

A [classical example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariable_calculus#Limits_and_continuity) of a limit that returns the same value when approached from any line, but still doesn't exist, is:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$$
Approaching along the line $y=mx$ gives:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2mx}{x^4+m^2x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{mx}{x^2+m^2}=0$$for any value of $m$. But when you approach along $y=x^2$, you get:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2x^2}{x^4+x^4} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^4}{2x^4}= \frac{1}{2}$$
This is sufficient to conclude that the limit does not exist.

> Limit exists

For the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$
you can try as many paths as you want, you'll always find $0$. To show that the limit is in fact $0$, you could do the following:
$$\left| \frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2} \right| = \left| y \right|\left| \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2} \right| \le \left| y \right| \to 0$$

Comment: Thank you very much @StackTD

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} {y\over x}$ does not exist:
$$\eqalign{
\lim_{(x,x)\to (0,0)} {x\over x} &= \lim_{x\to0}{x \over x} = 1\cr
\lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)} {0\over x} &= \lim_{x\to0}{0 \over x} = 0\cr
}$$
Even if $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,rx)\to(0,0)} f(x,rx)$ exists, $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)$ might not exist, because you might have
$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,rx)\to(0,0)} f(x,rx) \not= \lim_{(x,x^2)\to(0,0)} f(x,x^2)$. (I'm sure someone will chime in with an example ...)

Comment: Ok, so what methods are there to solve such a limit?

Comment: It's easier to show that a limit of $f(x,y)$ does not exist, by the method above. If you want to prove that a limit does exist, you still have algebraic manipulation and the squeeze theorem.